# Logging number of records queried from each shard

Tags: database, jdbc, sharding

```
PreparedStatement sm = conn.prepareStatement(
                        SQL,
                        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
                ) 
ResultSet rs = sm.executeQuery();
```

given a query using JDBC on a sharded table using ShardingSphere how would I be able to know which record from which physical table and datasource?

I'd like to log something like:

```
 *** records extracted from table *** of datasource ***
 *** records extracted from table *** of datasource ***
 *** records extracted from table *** of datasource ***
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

which release are you using? Generally, you can set `sql.show` = `true` to log the routing info (All the actual SQLs on specific physical data sources for each logic SQL), like,

```yaml
props:
  sql-show: false
```

If you wanna learn more, please visit
https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/5.2.1/en/user-manual/shardingsphere-jdbc/yaml-config/rules/sharding/

Comment: I'm using 4.0.1, that would work too if there is no workaround, it generates a bit more log than what I strictly need but does do it nonetheless. Thanks!